# **ImportError**: unable to load extension module '/home/wyx/pypy3env/site-packages/numpy/core/**multiarray.pypy3-52.so**':

Tags: python, numpy, pypy

I created a virtualenv of **PyPy 5.2.0-alpha0 with GCC 4.6.3** on Ubuntu 14.04.
After that installed numpy (using pip) for pypy successfully, when i do
`import numpy` in the pypy3 intepreter the following error occurrs:

```
ImportError: unable to load extension module
'/home/wyx/pypy3env/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.pypy3-52.so':
/home/wyx/pypy3env/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.pypy3-52.so:
undefined symbol: PyUnicode_GetLength
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix this, I'm afraid. `pypy3` 5.2 does not support `numpy`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try another pypy version.

Comment: Same thing with `pypy3` 5.5. Which `pypy` version supports `numpy`?